# How to modify the width of first column of bootstrap grid inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid

How to double the width of first column (from col-xx-4 to col-xx-8) with AngularJS?

It's quite easy with Bootstrap itself (you'll see it in attached plunker Section B).

I try to do the same in section A - with AngularJS.

When I use $first selector with

`ng-class='{"post col-xs-8":$first}'`

all columns except first one are ok. Unfortunately, first column gets class col-xx-4, not the col-xx-12 and it takes only 1/4 of free space, not full width.

How to select it and change this to look like in section B?
http://plnkr.co/edit/PvkjyDg19oM3bQaqJWIK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in data" ng-class='{"post col-xs-8":$first, "col-xs-4":!$first}'>
    <p class="color">{{a}}</p>
 </div>
```

The parent divs of all the child divs were missed to set width, except the first column.

Comment: Thank you very much :) was lost in this simple issue